# Bootstrap datetimepicker dont works whats the problem?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

What am I doing wrong ? this is my html codes for datetimepicker bootstrap.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hoşgeldin Temsilci</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link href="css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
      <link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" />

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker4').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });
        });
</script>
      <link href="css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="js/Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I think my code have no problem but it not works. When i click ,datepicker doesnt open. Please help.

Comment: Your example worked for me, but there was a browser console message: `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3`

Comment: i get this error 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (temsilci.aspx:115)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Which browser are you using? I simply copy/pasted your code from above and ran it as-is. (even though the jquery version is > 3) I used Firefox version 64. Also, try moving the script block (with the document ready) to a point before the closing body tag so that is the last item in the body.

Comment: i use chrome. my other scripts are work fine. but this datetimepicker i cant ran. so i gived up on it.

Comment: It also works on Chrome for me, with the same jQuery message in my first comment, but oh well...

Comment: thanks anyway for info :)